# What folders does Rails 4.1 include in autoload

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a Ruby on Rails 4.1 app with Ruby 2.11. The structure is Domain -> Team -> User. So, a user belongs to a team and I sometimes need to make a team from a domain (so they are associated). Think Starbucks -> NY Central Team -> Mr Barista.

I have made some builder classes and put them in app/builders, but when I try to use the class it says uninitialized constant in the Rails console. So, for example, I have the file in `app/builders/team_builder.rb`:

```
class TeamBuilder

  attr_reader :domain, :params

  def initialize(domain, params = {})
    @domain = domain
    @params = params
  end

  def build
    domain.teams.build(params)
  end

end
```

But when I type `TeamBuilder.new(domain, name: 'Team name here!')` I get the response

```
NameError: uninitialized constant TeamBuilder
```

It seems like it does not recognise the new class I have added above, which makes me think it is not loading it. But I thought that all sub-directories in app/ were loaded.

Totally stumped on this one, and I cannot find a guide or documentation on this (maybe it's there - somewhere...)

Comment: Have you exited your Rails console and restarted it? You are right that everything in app/ is autoloaded.

Comment: Yes. I have ven reset the machine and restarted the dev environment and started a new Rails console - it still can't see the class and gives the uninitialized constant error. I think I might have found a bug? Pushing it to Heroku and production to see what happens in that console too. [Answer: Same thing happens on Heroku]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into your rails console (rails c) and type the following:

`YourAppName::Application.config.eager_load_paths`

(where YourAppName is whatever it is called in your environment.rb where initialize! is called). This should show you all the paths automatically loaded into your application (before customizing).

It looks like the automatic path adding magic is happening in here https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb

Comment: This is what enabled me to fix it, seeing the load paths. It's too long to go into, but it was a simple snafu and not a Rails bug or anything - thanks for your helpful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) indicate you can run:

`bin/rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'`

to view in terminal