# Rails console does not autoload all directories under /app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my Rails 5 project, I have added a new subdirectory to the `app` directory, `app/services`, which contains a simple `Company` service module for looking up company information that may change over time (such as contact phone number):

```
- project
  - app
    - services
      - company.rb
```

The `Company` module runs fine on the development server, and the tests for the module all run without a problem. This is expected, since all subdirectories of `app` are included in `autoload_paths` by default.

However, I cannot access this module from the Rails console. From the console, `app/services` is not included in `autoload_paths`.

From the server runtime (near the bottom in both query results):

```
>> ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
 => ["project/app/assets",
     "project/app/channels",
     "project/app/controllers",
     "project/app/controllers/concerns",
     "project/app/helpers",
     "project/app/jobs",
     "project/app/mailers",
     "project/app/models",
     "project/app/models/concerns",
     "project/app/services",
     "project/test/mailers/previews"]

>> Rails.application.config.eager_load_paths
 => ["project/app/assets",
     "project/app/channels",
     "project/app/controllers",
     "project/app/controllers/concerns",
     "project/app/helpers",
     "project/app/jobs",
     "project/app/mailers",
     "project/app/models",
     "project/app/models/concerns",
     "project/app/services"]

>> Company
 => Company
```

But from the console:

```
>> ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths
 => ["project/app/assets",
     "project/app/channels",
     "project/app/controllers",
     "project/app/controllers/concerns",
     "project/app/helpers",
     "project/app/jobs",
     "project/app/mailers",
     "project/app/models",
     "project/app/models/concerns",
     "project/test/mailers/previews"] 

>> Rails.application.config.eager_load_paths
 => ["project/app/assets",
     "project/app/channels",
     "project/app/controllers",
     "project/app/controllers/concerns",
     "project/app/helpers",
     "project/app/jobs",
     "project/app/mailers",
     "project/app/models",
     "project/app/models/concerns"]

>> Company
 => NameError: uninitialized constant Company
```

(`Rails.application.config.autoload_paths` is empty in both cases.)

What gives? I can't seem to find this documented anywhere. All documentation takes it for granted that all subdirectories of `app` are always autoloaded.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: [Here is a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23413851/6111895) that seems to point in the right direction but leaves the actual resolution tantalizingly out of reach. I am a bit wary of going down the Rails guts rabbit hole, which is where this question leads, but perhaps that is necessary.

Comment: Try adding `config.autoload_paths += ["#{Rails.root}/app/services"]` to your `config/application.rb` file.

Comment: this is odd. just as a sanity check, have you actually re-started the console?

Comment: this is the documentation you are looking for https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/guides/source/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.md#autoload_paths

Comment: while trying to understand the autoload logic, i cleaned some rails code https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27221

Comment: Hey @phoet. I did restart the console many times while trying to debug this. The Rails Guides doc you cited seems to indicate this shouldn't be happening:

"Rails is always able to autoload provided its environment is in place...The console autoloads, the test suite autoloads, and of course the application autoloads."

And later:

"`autoload_paths`...by default...contains: All subdirectories of `app` in the application and engines present at boot time...They do not need to be the default ones, any custom directories like `app/workers` belong automatically to `autoload_paths`."

Comment: Here is a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23413851/6111895) that may or may not be informative. The original author unfortunately declined to describe how he or she resolved the issue.

@ThanhHuynh, your solution will work, but I don't want to add anything to the code base that, by all accounts, should not be necessary, especially if it is only to get the Rails console to behave.

Comment: i would still argue that there should not be any difference. could there be anything that differs in your "server" and "console" runtimes?

Comment: another sanity check idea would be to use different names. try to change directory, file and class names to something that should not have collisions in the codebase. rails classloading behaves slightly different when class caching is enabled.

Comment: @phoet Today I found the `services` directory in my `autoload_paths` on the console, and the `Company` module available there. Scratching my head, I created an additional directory and test module in my project, `app/test/test_module.rb`, and this recreated the original behavior. It was available in the server but not the console. This persists even after restarting everything. You mentioned class caching, and now this looks like some kind of caching behavior. I'm not very familiar with the Rails guts; where can I learn more about constant caching behavior?

Comment: restarting the server should eliminate all cached classes.

Answer (score 3):

Restart spring.

```
$ spring stop
$ rails console
```

This solved the same problem for me.

Comment: This is awful, even restarting spring, it seems to work at it own will. Sometimes calling `rails c` works but  then`rspec` stops. When rspec works, `rails s` doesn't. Autoload is a nightmare sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

> I just simply changed it to eager load, and things worked fine
> `config.eager_load = true`

I did it too and its works now, even changing the variable to false again

Answer (score -1):

As noted in the comments, I looked in the Rails docs, it referred to `eager_load` in the environment settings.  When running in the console I am running in `development`.  I looked in the `config/environments/development` and saw it was not eager loading by default.

```
# Do not eager load code on boot.
config.eager_load = false
```

I just simply changed it to eager load, and things worked fine

```
config.eager_load = true
```